# Magento 2 - Accidentally deleted 'admin_passwords' table, no backups

Tags: magento2, database

I accidentally dropped the table 'admin_passwords'.

What is the command that would re-create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you removed that table accidentally then you can use following sql command to create "admin_passwords" table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin_passwords` (
`password_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Password 
Id',
`user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'User Id',
`password_hash` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Password Hash',
`expires` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Expires',
`last_updated` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Last Updated',
PRIMARY KEY (`password_id`),
KEY `ADMIN_PASSWORDS_USER_ID` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Admin Passwords';
```

Use PhpMyAdmin interface to run above sql.

For your information "admin_user" is a table in Magento 2 where admin password store by default.

Hope this helps!